# How to consider two dates in Google Sheets, in separate columns, and when a 2nd date is detected at all, yield custom text?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, spreadsheet

I have a date in column A, for example: 1/2/2022. When 30 days have passed, I use the following formula to tell me something has expired:

```
=AND($A2<=(TODAY()-30),$A2<>"")
```

The result if expired: TRUE.

Sometimes, I have another value in column B. This value indicates when something has been closed and expiration should no longer apply.

How can I modify the above formula to take my column B date into consideration? so that if any value is detected in column B at all, my result will be custom text, like "N/A"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`IF`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093364?hl=en) or [`IFS`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/7014145?hl=en) combined with [`ISDATE`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/9061381?hl=en) or [`ISBLANK`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093290?hl=en):

```
=IFS(ISDATE(B2),"N/A",AND($A2<=(TODAY()-30),$A2<>""),"Yes",TRUE,"No")
```

(put "N/A" if B2 is a date, "Yes" if your original formula evaluates to TRUE, otherwise "No")

or

```
=IFS(AND(ISBLANK(B2),$A2<=(TODAY()-30),$A2<>""),"Yes",ISBLANK(B2),"No",TRUE,"N/A")
```

Comment: This works! Is there any way to make it say "YES" rather than True? Thank you so much

Comment: @topredBird12355 In that case you have multiple conditions so `IFS` makes more sense.  I've updated the answer to show how to do that.